# VueRouter/Firebase: URL typed in browser renders dynamic route only when typed twice

Tags: firebase, vue.js, async-await, vue-router

I'm trying to get vue-router to redirect to a dynamic url constructed from a Firebase document id, when accessing the root url, like this:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    beforeEnter: async () => {
      let acuerdos = await db.collection("acuerdos").orderBy("fecha", "desc").get()
      let ultimoAcuerdo = acuerdos.docs[0].id
      router.push({ path: `/acuerdos/${ultimoAcuerdo}`})
    }
  }
```

This works fine, for the most part. The only problem is that, when the redirect is done (to, say `/acuerdos/18-06-2020`) and the view is rendered, if I want to type in another url (for example, to `/acuerdos/11-06-2020`), it fails to do anything; but then it'll work just fine if I hit enter again on the same url.

For the record, I used to experience a similar issue when navigating from one dynamic route to another even from within the app's `<router-link>`, and I solved it by using `<router-view :key="$route.fullPath"/>`. So maybe the answer would be to asing a similar `key` prop to the route, but I wouldn't know how to do that from within the router's `index.js` file.

Thanks for any pointers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope the route is defined in the router config; I replicated something similar in codesandbox and I'm able to get it working.

Only difference is I've used the `next` method over `router.push` in the `beforeEnter` guard as I wasn't sure where you're getting the router object from.

```
beforeEnter(to, from, next) {
  next({ path: "/acuerdos/01-01-2001" });
}
```

You can try it here,

[image: Edit Vue Routing Example]

As a side note, I prefer routing with named routes as it seems cleaner and is more reliable in my personal opinion,

```
next({
  name: 'Acuerdos',
  params: {
    date: ultimoAcuerdo
  }
})
```

This way even if the route path changes, your code won't break.

Comment: Sorry I took so long to try it out. It worked flawlessly. And also implemented your named route solution. So double thanks :)